# Conditional expectation of a logistic-distributed random variable

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

How can I find the conditional expectation $E[X|X > k]$ of a random variable $X$ distributed logistically with parameters $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s \ge 0$, cumulative distribution function $$F(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(x-\mu)/s}}$$ and probability density function $$f(x) = \frac{e^{-(x-\mu)/s}}{s(1+e^{-(x-\mu)/s})^2}$$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$?

I am looking for a way to get the conditional expectation without having to use a simulation.

Comment: Without having looked at this at all, have you tried calculating $E[X\mid X > k] = \int_k^\infty x f(x) \, \mathrm dx$?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how to evaluate the integral.